# Cannot add instruction tiles to EV3 brick program.

Tags: ev3

I was using the EV3 brick program software included in the ev3 Brick and I can no longer add instructions. I think I've reached the max length. Is there a way around this? Can I run a second program after finishing the original one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Large programs can be difficult.

Usually it is better to divide a large program into pieces, where each piece is a MyBlock.

To create a MyBlock, select a group of program blocks and then find the "Create MyBlock ..." from the toolbar.  I think it's at Edit -> Create My Block ...

A series of dialog boxes will appear, complete them and the selected blocks will be stuffed inside the MyBlock, and the program will be altered to use the new MyBlock.  Double click the MyBlock and there will be the program elements that were originally selected.

Practice on a smaller program before attempting on a large program.